# JavaFXPorts foreign language keyboard

Tags: android, javafx, javafxports

I have just made a simple javafxports app. It has textAreas in VBoxes. The problem is that installed on android, there is no way I can write on the textareas in greek language. English can be inserted (latin in general) but no greek. I have tried this solution [JavaFxPorts TextField Issue - Android Keyboard wont function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316573/javafxports-textfield-issue-android-keyboard-wont-function), but it didn't work.

I have also tried using Gluon Mobile, and I didn't face any such problem in the sample app with an extra TextArea. But for now I have to finish this javaFXPorts app (and it certainly would be necessary for this porting system to be usable for other languages as well). Any help is greatly welcomed!

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062355/gluonmobile-has-font-bug-on-android-os/44520724#44520724)? You'll need a font that JavaFXPorts doesn't provide.

Comment: Thank you very much @José for your help.I could just continue developing on the Gluon Mobile platform but as I experienced there is no android text copy-paste functionality, which is needed for my app. Keep up the good work and thanks again!

Comment: If there is such a feature missing, you can try to add it yourself, request it here (post it as a question) or ask it directly to Gluon's support (support at gluonhq.com)

Comment: For instance, you can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561927/textfield-copy-action-on-long-hold-copy-popup). It shows how you can enable the ContextMenu for TextFields, with the usual copy, select, paste options.